# How to find a file in Project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file

I'm getting a problem to find a file from project. I am getting this file using code but I can't get it using url.

Please help me out from this problem.

Here is the path of file

> Users/yatish/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/65048208-DC46-4B30-9526-470D6D8081D3/data/Containers/Data/Application/2E7EFDA0-9C0C-4440-962D-610C2AC18DDD/Documents/file.txt

Here is the code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *Path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@%@",documentsDirectory,@"file"@".txt"];
[str writeToFile:Path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

NSString *fn=@"file";
NSString *searchFilename =[fn stringByAppendingString:@".txt"]; // name of the PDF you are searching for
NSArray *pathss = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectorys = [pathss objectAtIndex:0];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:documentsDirectorys];
NSString *documentsSubpath;
BOOL fileFound = false;

while (documentsSubpath = [direnum nextObject])
{
    if (![documentsSubpath.lastPathComponent isEqual:searchFilename]) {
        continue;
        fileFound=NO;
    }

    NSLog(@"found %@", documentsSubpath);
    fileFound =YES;
}
if(fileFound){
   NSLog(@"File Found");///this line is execute when i run this code
}
```

Comment: I already find file in finder but not display the file

Answer (score 0):

In code, you can use:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithPath: documentsSubpath];
```

And that will be the path to your file.

If you want to see the actual file, go to the Macintosh Finder and click "Go To Folder" (it's under the "Go" menu, or <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> all together).  Then type in your path ***MINUS*** the last path component, which is the filename.  In your case, that is "`/Users/yatish/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/65048208-DC46-4B30-9526-470D6D8081D3/data/Containers/Data/Application/2E7EFDA0-9C0C-4440-962D-610C2AC18DDD/Documents`".

Comment: This code already working but i want to see file physically where is it. I search this path in finder and Shit+Command+G but file is not found, where i am wrong please tell me...

Comment: You missed the leading slash before "`/Users`".